# How to send email from contact page without using a plugin

Tags: wp-mail

How can I send an email from a contact page in WordPress without using a plugin? Does WordPress have a default function by which I can send email?

Comment: Yes, you've tagged your question with that function's name. :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make a contact form without PHP code that sends the email. If you do not use a plugin, you have to write the code yourself and put it somewhere else, like in a theme. But putting it in a plugin is better. You also cannot put PHP code in the page or post (without a plugin for that).

The PHP function that WordPress provides for sending an email [wp_mail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) is for use in a plugin or theme (not in a page or post, since you cannot add PHP there).